# Is a Discord ID (ulong number) an acceptable form of authentication?

Tags: discord

I want to have a Bot that when recieving a command, it will perform an action based on the context (who sent the message) that I want to be secure, in that I don't want another user to be able to affect the user's data.

The user is grabbed from the context then the Discord ID (ulong number **not** username#1234) is used to key into a database entry based on that ID.

Assuming that this is only accessible through the bot, which only performs this command based off of context. Is it an acceptable form of authentication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, using the UserId as a means of determining (authenticating) the user that executed a command is perfectly fine. These IDs are unique per user across all of discord and will not change regardless of username or nickname changes. Setting the primary key in the database to this id is also ok.

Answer (score 0):

Actually these ID are available to everyone.

To access it you need to activate the developper mode in the app option :[image: discord developer mode option] then you'll just need to right click anyone and click `copy ID`

Comment: I am aware. But as the bot performs commands on the user's behalf based on context, the only way to cause issues is if someone can spoof another user.

Comment: I'm almost sure discord prevent things like this from happening, it would be a big fail in security if anyone could send message on behalf of another

Comment: Then I'm fairly sure my answer is yes?

Comment: AFAIK yes it is ;)